# Specifying both "methods" and index operator in Lua metatable

Tags: lua, metatable, lua-userdata

I need userdata objects to support both methods and the index operator (with integer indices). Is there a way to achieve this in a common metatable without simulating methods via a function?

I tried chaining metatables, by setting `metatable(object).__index` to a table with the actual methods, and `metatable(metatable(object).__index).__index` to a function that implements the index operator. However, that function is called with the first `__index` table as an argument, instead of the original object. Tbh this seems like a design oversight, since it makes much more sense to pass the original object when the `__index` metamethod is a function. Regardless, is there a way to achieve what I want without explicitly checking for method names in the `__index` function?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a single __index function that both refers to the method table and handles integer keys.

```
function metatable:__index(key)
  if type(key) == 'string' then
    return methodTable[key]
  elseif type(key) == 'number' then
    return key * 42 + #self
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set `__index` to a table, Lua automatically does a normal table lookup for the key in the `__index` table. It's completely equivalent to `debug.getmetatable(obj).__index[k]`, and will do a recursive `__index` lookup or function call if the `__index` table has its own `__index` table.